# How to know application name through Oracle Table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I tried by this

```
select module from v$sqlarea where sql_fulltext LIKE '%begin ORACLE_PKG%'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the module name by your current sql provided the module name is set by using `dbms_application_info.set_module` method within the related application :

```
declare
  v_module_name varchar2(150);
begin
  v_module_name := get_module_name;  -- a presumed function that brings the module name
  dbms_application_info.set_module( module_name => v_module_name, action_name => 'some duty');
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the module that has already been set via a call to `DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE`, you can get that with this expression:

```
SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','MODULE')
```

If you want the current PL/SQL package name, you can get that with this expression:

```
$$PLSQL_UNIT
```

Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE my_pkg AS
  PROCEDURE p;
END my_pkg;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY my_pkg AS
  PROCEDURE p IS
  BEGIN
    dbms_application_info.set_module ( module_name => 'MY_MODULE', action_name => 'MY_ACTION' );
    dbms_output.put_line('Current module = ' || SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','MODULE'));
    dbms_output.put_line('Current program unit = ' || $$PLSQL_UNIT);
  END p;    
END my_pkg;

exec my_pkg.p;
```

> ```
> Current module = MY_MODULE
> Current program unit = MY_PKG
> ```